# Can't run software-properties-gtk or add repositories through Terminal

Tags: software-installation, update-manager, add-apt-repository

Today, I wanted to see how Elementary OS' Pantheon desktop environment would work with my workflow. I didn't care much for it, so I removed all traces (I could easily find on my own) using Synaptic. Unfortunately for me, this introduced a couple of problems I've so far been unable to solve. Firstly, `software-properties-gtk` fails to open with the [following error](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dfzNm8SSWY/), and secondly, I can't add or remove PPAs through the terminal, as [this error](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J6k5msvTFR/) is thrown.

I can still install software, as long as it's a part of my currently added repositories. I have tried restoring my sources.list file to original and that hasn't helped, and I've also tried reinstalling relevant packages and their dependencies (like `software-properties-gtk`) but so far nothing has helped. I've been searching for answers online for the past few hours and I've come up with nothing to show for it, so I now must ask for help online, especially since I don't want to reinstall (again). Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I forgot to add that earlier.

Comment: *I wanted to see how Elementary OS' Pantheon desktop environment:* Did you add some PPA? Which packages were installed when you installed that DE?

Comment: @Kulfy I followed instructions here: [link](https://itsubuntu.com/top-desktop-environments-for-ubuntu-20-04-lts/) and added several Elementary OS PPAs (daily, OS-patches, testing, elementary-tweaks-daily). Then, I used `sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop elementary-tweaks` which installed a lot of packages, about 1.2GB worth. I used Synaptic to track them all down and remove them.

Comment: I tried adding PPAs to my system running 20.04. I wasn't able to add testing and  elementary-tweaks-daily. What does `lsb_release -a` reports?

Comment: @Kulfy `lsb_release -a` reports the system as being Elementary OS 6.0 Next. Here's the pastebin output: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9WyHXK2r8P/)

Comment: Do you still have PPAs added? What is the output of `zgrep 'install ' /var/log/dpkg.log* | sort | cut -f1,2,4 -d' '`?

Comment: @Kulfy according to Stacer, they're still there, but not enabled (the switch is red, indicating "off"). Also, the output of the above command is over 1,000 lines long, which you can see here. [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vxdPyhhGRq/), and I still don't think it's the complete list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108965/discussion-between-kulfy-and-richie-goldsworthy).

Comment: @RichieGoldsworthy, have you fixed it? I have exact problem. Tried installing Pantheon, and add 4-5 ppa (incl /daily a& tweaks, which failed), and ended up exactly like yours. lsb-release is showing elementary-os and  software-properties-gtk doesn't open. Please let me know if you've fixed